# Usage of the nth-root function in cryptography

Tags: function-evaluation

Having offered a fast integer nth-root algorithm to a bigint library that is also used for cryptography I was asked if it does its work in constant time, so I took a look at the literature to see how other programmers solved that problem and found—nothing.

That leads to the question: is there any cryptographic algorithm out there—and in use— that needs an integer nth-root function?

**EDIT:** "integer nth-root function" here means a plain, vanilla truncating nth-root function $k = \lfloor m^{1/n} \rfloor$ with the restrictions $\{k, m, n\} \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $n > 0$.

Comment: Are you asking about the n-th root function over a finite ring, a finite field, or over the reals?

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Not the reals in this case (I don't think a truncating nth-root function would make much sense but I might err, of course) but I'm completely open to any hint. I can save a lot of work (and headaches) if there is no algorithm known to the experts that uses a nth-root function. I can still add it later if somebody complains but it is cheaper if I can spare that work for now.

Comment: The reason why I ask is because some cryptosystems do use modular n-th roots over a ring - RSA decryption is an e-th root modulo $p*q$, Paillier decryption involves an n-th root modulo $n^2$, etc.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Ah, thanks for clarifying. No, no modular nth-roots, just a plain vanilla truncating nth-root. Should I edit my question to add a note to that regard?

Comment: that might help yes :)

Comment: Integer $n^{\mathit{th}}$ root is very useful for breaking stupid uses of RSA.  Fortunately the serious uses of it, like RSA-KEM for encryption, are not vulnerable to this.  But nobody cares if an attack runs in constant time.

Comment: BTW: in the crypto world, "constant time" means time independent of the inputs.  In your case, it's rather unlikely; your code likely takes somewhat more time on inputs $m = \lfloor 2^{1000000} \cdot \pi \rfloor$, $n=2$ than it does for $m = 4$, $n = 2$

Comment: @poncho keys are mostly fixed in their bit-size so it is enough if it runs in constant time for every input in the range $2^{k-1} < n < 2^k$. And in the case of bigint you also need to make the underlying arithmetic for the big-digits do their things in constant time. That is a *lot* of work that I want to avoid if possible, hence my question ;-)

Comment: well then my answer to your question would be "not that I know of", but additional opinions of other members might be preferable :)